# using comparator filter in list filter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I'm a bit stuck trying to create a filter that can be used in a ng-repeat as well as in the controller.

I've created some controller filters of the form

```
$scope.myfilter = function($item){
    if($item == "blah"){
         return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

but discovered the ones you attach to the module, that accept lists instead.

```
angular.module('filters',[])
filter(function(){
    return function(list){
        //filter code goes here.
    }
});
```

obviously it can run the comparator versions on lists since it does it for ng-repeats. Is there a easy way to run the comparator filters inside the list based ones? I'm a bit confused as to when you would use one over the other?

Comment: If i understood right, you want to know difference between filtering data in script and filtering inside ng-repeat. If so - it depends, if you have large amount of data - probably would be better to filter them before inserting to `ng-repeat`, `var result = array.filter(function(obj){ return obj == 'someval'})` can help, but if you have small data, then it doesn't really matter thought

Comment: no what  I want is one filter that can be used in both places. It seems like there are too similar methods of filtering. So I'm figuring out if I need to rewrite the code I already have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pplease see here http://jsbin.com/wajecu/2/edit

more documentation you can find here https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09

**filter:**

```
 app.filter('myfilter', function() {
        return function(input) {
          var filtered = [];

          angular.forEach(input, function (value){
             if(value == "blah"){ filtered.push(value); }   

          });
            return filtered;   

        };
     });
```

**Controller:**

```
app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope,$filter){      

      $scope.items = ["blah", "ech", "mech"];
      //you can use your filter inside controller in that way:
      $scope.filtered= $filter('myfilter')($scope.items);

});
```

**html:**

```
  <p ng-repeat="item in items | myfilter ">{{item}}</p>
```